# Logstash Not Reading "File" Input

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to use file as an input to logstash.Here is my logstash.conf

```
input {
     file {
          path => "/home/dxp/elb.log"
          type => "elb"
          start_position => "beginning"
          sincedb_path => "/home/dxp/log.db"
          }
    }

        filter {
        if [type] == "elb" {
                grok {
                    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int} %{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int} %{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int} %{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int} %{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} %{QS:request}" ]
                }
            }
        }
        output
        {
          elasticsearch {
               hosts => "10.99.0.180:9200"
               manage_template => false
               index => "elblog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
               document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
           }
        }
```

My logs show this:
`[2017-10-27T13:11:31,164][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.file     ]_globbed_files: /home/dxp/elb.log: glob is []`: I guess my file has not been read by logstash, so a new index is not formed in elasticsearch.
 Please help me with what i am missing in this.

Comment: Perhaps it's a permission problem? The user running logstash might not have the right to access the folder/file.

Comment: @baudsp user running logstash means? We run logstash through docker.  Also my input file haa 777 permission

Comment: I've never used docker. So I don't have any other idea.